# Error 404 when submitting form in Spring MVC web app

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

I am trying an example from [*www.tutorialspoint.com*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm) for Spring MVC form handling. I am getting the following when clicking submit button in the page when running in a browser:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWeb/addStudent

type Status report

message /HelloWeb/addStudent

description The requested resource is not available.
```

This is the *web*.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>NProject</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>student.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Servlet config file is *HelloWeb-servlet.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="bundle" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3000" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Controller file is:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentCOntroller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView student(){
        return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addstudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student,
                            ModelMap  model,
                            BindingResult result) {
        model.addAttribute("name",student.getName());
        model.addAttribute("age",student.getAge());
        model.addAttribute("id",student.getId());

        return "result";
    }
}
```

These are the JSP files:

*student.jsp*

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Student Information</h2>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

*result.jsp*:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>${name}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>${age}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>${id}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to figure out this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your action from student.jsp to

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addStudent">
```

It should work.

Comment: In the OP's case your suggestion makes no difference. See the link for the tutorial the OP talks about in the question body.

Comment: @user2083175 So what was the reason? Using `action="addStudent"` instead of `action="/HelloWeb/addStudent"` is **definitely not** the reason. So what was it?

Comment: using action="addstudent" is a part of the error,declaration of addstudent in student.jsp is different from what i declared in the studentcontroller.java "S" in caps in student.jsp and i have added the ResourceViewResolver in the bean class,thus it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Define package bundle in your controller.

```
package bundle;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `student.jsp`, change the line to

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addStudent">
```

It works